# Dropping row in pandas if 2 columns in the same row have NAN value in it

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and trying to complete the following:

I have a dataframe which look like this:

```
row    A     B     
1      abc   abc 
2      abc   
3            abc 
4
5      abc   abc
```

My desired output would look like this:

```
row    A     B     
1      abc   abc 
2      abc   
3            abc 
5      abc   abc
```

I am trying to drop rows if there is no value in both A and B columns:

```
if finalized_export_cf[finalized_export_cf['A']].str.len()<2:
    if finalized_export_cf[finalized_export_cf['B']].str.len()<2:
        finalized_export_cf[finalized_export_cf['B']].drop()
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

How could I drop values when both columns have an empty cell?
Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whether all rows have a null by using `.isnull()` and `all()` in a chain. `isnull()` produces a dataframe with booleans, and `all(axis=1)` checks whether all values in a given rows are true. If that's the case, that means that all values in the rows are nulls:

```
inds = df[["A", "B"]].isnull().all(axis=1)
```

You can then use `inds` to clean up all rows that have only nulls. First negate it using the tilda `~`, or else you can only missing values:

```
df = df.loc[~inds, :]
```

Comment: I have 10 columns and only need to check 2 of those, how would I proceed with this set up?

Answer (score 2):

If missing values are `NaN`s then use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with `all` and subset parameter:

```
print (df)
   row    A    B
0    1  abc  abc
1    2  abc  NaN
2    3  NaN  abc
3    4  NaN  NaN
4    5  abc  abc

df = df.dropna(how='all', subset=['A','B'])
print (df)
   row    A    B
0    1  abc  abc
1    2  abc  NaN
2    3  NaN  abc
4    5  abc  abc
```

Or if empty value is empty string use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with compare not equal `''`:

```
print (df)
   row    A    B
0    1  abc  abc
1    2  abc     
2    3       abc
3    4          
4    5  abc  abc


df = df[df[['A','B']].ne('').any(axis=1)]
print (df)
   row    A    B
0    1  abc  abc
1    2  abc     
2    3       abc
4    5  abc  abc
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, does this drop rows only if both A and B columns are empty or either one of those?

Comment: @KenHBS - sure, rows are removed

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - It test only `A, B` columns - all columns specified in subset parameter

Answer (score 2):

For your use case you can create a mask and get the values where A & B are not True:

```
mask = df.isna()
df[~((mask.A == True) & (mask.B == True))]
```

output:

```
   row    A    B
0    1  abc  abc
1    2  abc  NaN
2    3  NaN  abc
4    5  abc  abc
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have only two columns - you can use the `how` attribute of the [pandas.dataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) by setting it to 'all':

```
df.dropna(how='all')
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all we need to change the blank spaces to NaN

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$',np.nan,regex=True)
```

then drop na whilst sub-setting your rows

```
df.dropna(subset=['A','B'],how='all').fillna(' ') # if you want spaces for na
print(df)
    row    A    B
0    1  abc  abc
1    2  abc     
2    3  abc     
4    5  abc  abc
```

Comment: @Jonas Palačionis - I suggest you use this answer - this will work